# Can coredata predicates query 3rd level objects

Tags: objective-c, ios4, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to do some more complicated coredata queries with little success.

So far I have got this working successfully:

```
events.@count != 0
```

But then I have tried this (in order to test dependents exist)

```
events.event.dependents.@count !=0
events.dependents.@count !=0
```

With a "Unsupported function expression count:(events.event.dependents)" error.

What I am ideally trying to do is:

```
ANY events.event.dependents.dependent.dependentId == 13500
ANY events.dependents.dependentId == 13500
```

I wish I had the power of SQL (which Im more familiar with) :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A collection operator cannot transverse a to-many relationship to another key in a keypath. In this case, `events` by convention would be a to_many relationship so I presume the collection operator is choking on that.

You're making a mistake very common to those skilled at SQL but new to Core Data. Your trying to treat Core Data as just an SQL wrapper and trying to shoehorn it a SQL design pattern. Don't do that.

You're problem here is that you are approaching the problem backwards. Because Core Data is an object graph, the most common pattern is to perform a fetch to find a specific object that possess the attribute you want to test against and the walk those object's relationships to find related objects.

So, in this case, you should perform a fetch against the entity that has the `dependentID` attribute. That will return one or more objects (presumably one in this case.) Then to find the related objects you would walk the keypath backwards from the way you have it now. So:

`dependent.dependents.event.events`

It's hard to be more descriptive without knowing what your data model looks like but you get the idea.

In SQL, despite it being a relational system, relationships are relatively weak compared to their use in Core Data. In SQL, you produce relationships in the fetch code. In Core Data, they are encoded into the object graph when the objects are created. That means you have to do far less work find persisted data. A fetch just plucks one (or a small number) of threads from a vast fabric that let you unweave the entire thing by tugging on the relationships.